# Laravel 7: How to access a function in User model from API without signing in

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a function in the user model used to send the API email verification message. It works fine in the registration function after User::create

```
 $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'sms_code' => $sms_code,
    ]);

    $user->sendApiEmailVerificationNotification();
```

Now I'm trying to resend the verification email in another function

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('email', $email)->first();
$user->sendApiEmailVerificationNotification();
```

User model:

```
public function sendApiEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $this->notify(new VerifyApiEmail);
}
```

But I get

```
"message": "Call to undefined method stdClass::sendApiEmailVerificationNotification()",
```

How to use this function using the $user object?

Comment: Try doing `User::where('email', $email)->first()` instead of `DB`

Comment: It's undefined since `sendApiEmailVerificationNotification` only exists on the eloquent object, not the stdclass created by ` DB::table('users')->where('email', $email)->first();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('email', $email)->first();
$user->sendApiEmailVerificationNotification();
```

use this:

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first());
$user->sendApiEmailVerificationNotification();
```

---

**why?**

The `User::where(..)` returns an *eloquent object* whilst *DB::table* does not.
`sendApiEmailVerificationNotification` only exists on *eloquent models* extending *authenticable*.